# How many percentage of my total needs of protein and carb must i use in pre-workout and post workout?

Tags: bodybuilding, nutrition

Given that, I need to receive `176g protein` and `304gram carb` in my bulking diet. And my workout takes about 1.5 hour long.

How many percentage of my total needs of protein and carb must i use in pre-workout and post workout?

I usually exercise in the evening and by that time i already got 20% of my needed protein and 50% of my needed carb in the breakfast and lunch. So, i need to plan for the remaining 80% and 50% of protein and carbs.

So, is there any optimized distribution for receiving carbs and proteins for the pre and post workout meals?

Comment: This post assumes a rather cute version of how the human body works. It takes your body 24-72 hours to digest protein based foods. That means: it takes a lot of time for it to get to your muscles after putting it in your mouth. So this doesn't matter. It will take so much time before it's going to be used anyhow and you won't get it all at once. Digestion is a complicated process. A couple of hours are irrelevant. Having a consistent diet is the way to go. If anything, if you eat fish or beef, your optimal pre workout meal is 3 days in advance

Comment: That's not a lot of protein (20%) before evening.. do you get most of protein at night? Best to spread it throughout the day. There's been studies that the body can only consumer roughly 30g of protein at a time so drinking 60g of whey is almost a waste. So preworkout 30g protein, a banana, preworkout supplements if you take any(creatine, beta alanine, etc..), I also drink beet juice. Carbs such as honey or banana are more important. Post workout drink your carb first, again a banana or apple, and 30g of whey.

Comment: Drink your carbs first before protein during pre and post workoutm. Protein slows down blood sugar, which is great for throughout the day but counterproductive when trying to get energy for a workout

Comment: @AceCabbie Could you please send me the link to the study which you mentioned?

Comment: @AceCabbie - I would also like to read that study.